# How to solve "Error: Invalid argument: JSON Value: {\n \"b64\...} is not of expected type float" error when performing batch transform on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, conv-neural-network, amazon-sagemaker

I have deployed a custom CNN on Sagemaker. The CNN takes as input .jpg files of a specific size. I prepared one S3 bucket containing :

```
model/
output/
input/
    |--photo1
    |--photo2
```

I created `inference.py` which has this code :

```py
import base64
import io
import json
import requests

def input_handler(data, context):
    """ Pre-process request input before it is sent to TensorFlow Serving REST API

    Args:
        data (obj): the request data stream
        context (Context): an object containing request and configuration details

    Returns:
        (dict): a JSON-serializable dict that contains request body and headers
    """

    if context.request_content_type == 'application/x-image':
        payload = data.read()
        encoded_image = base64.b64encode(payload).decode('utf-8')
        instance = [{"b64": encoded_image}]
        return json.dumps({"instances": instance})
    else:
        _return_error(415, 'Unsupported content type "{}"'.format(
            context.request_content_type or 'Unknown'))


def output_handler(response, context):
    """Post-process TensorFlow Serving output before it is returned to the client.

    Args:
        response (obj): the TensorFlow serving response
        context (Context): an object containing request and configuration details

    Returns:
        (bytes, string): data to return to client, response content type
    """
    if response.status_code != 200:
        _return_error(response.status_code, response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    response_content_type = context.accept_header
    prediction = response.content
    return prediction, response_content_type


def _return_error(code, message):
    raise ValueError('Error: {}, {}'.format(str(code), message))
```

I tried to follow this tutorial : https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container. From what I understand, every image of my input bucket gets converted into base64 file and put on a JSON object. But the thing is I have no clue what to change on the `inference.py` file to make my CNN accept JSON element of my images.

When I start the batch transform, I meet this error on the logs :

```
ValueError: Error: 400, { "error": "Failed to process element: 0 of \'instances\' list. Error: Invalid argument: JSON Value: {\n    \"b64\": \"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAzADMAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcG...igAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigANFFFAgooooGFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFIAooooAKKKKYBRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFAH/2Q==\"\n} Type: Object is not of expected type: float" }
```

So, could you explain what is wrong with my code ? Any help is much appreciated !